# How to fix top menu bar of my blog that is showing a blank space?

Tags: javascript

I have a blog which is hosted over blogger. I found an issue some time ago that keeps on bothering me. The top menu bar of my blog starts showing a blank option when it is opened on a mobile or the page is zoomed in. The blank option when clicked redirects to a 404 error page.

Please help me out to fix this.

You can visit my blog from [here](https://www.programmics.in).
Here is the template file of my [blog](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ybgGsdawKV6o6gHgOQKxVlUjQWSJX4Ik).

Edit 1 - When we try to zoom in the page and inspect the element is like this 
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zE3IZ.png)

On selecting the option we can see there is a option which is undefined.
[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iub7Y.png)

On deleting the option, ka-boom problem gets solved.
[Issue fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0whe.png)

but just when we reload the page, this thing appears again.

Thanks

Comment: Don't just link to a site, post all relevant code here. Create an example where we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the **selectnav** function generates the select dropdown from the children of the **ul** or **ol** node containing the menu...

Inside the menu list, you have a  element, which doesn't fit the schema and is rendered as **undefined** inside the  element.

You need to take the whole  element out of the menu list, so it won't be generated as a menu list item in the menu dropdown.

Comment: It's not working bro. Some of the scripts stops loading after it.

Comment: it must be a storage issue then, where have you defined your pages?

Comment: my blog is blogger hosted so the pages are self defined.

Comment: Ok I am updating the question with some more information.

Comment: I see now, the solutions is very simple... I will edit my answer now

Comment: But how can I take the whole element out of the menu. See the element is in linear form but just when the page is zoomed in, it gets suppressed under this menu. Is there any way we can remove that particular element that is causing the issue.

Comment: please help me bro